# PowerShell query: how to process a file

Tags: powershell

I often want to process a file resulting in a modified output file.  I can't seem to find the PowerShell way to do this - it always ends up looking like code in a one-liner, IYSWIM.  This is an example.

I have an LMHOSTS file.  Don't ask why!  I want to get a new LMHOSTS file that only contains servers that respond to pings.  I also want to pass through any comment lines.

Comment lines begin with a #.

Data lines are something like this (space-separated):

```
10.123.177.1    SVRDS1 #PRE #DOM:DOM1
```

or this:

```
10.241.177.30   SVRDS30 #PRE
```

This is what I've got (with thanks to [Luke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/55847/luke) for help with Ping-Host):

```
gc 'C:\work\lmhosts.txt' | % { if ($_ -like '#*') { $_ | out-file 'C:\work\lmhosts2.txt' -append } else { if ($(Ping-Host $_.Substring(0, $_.indexof(' ')) -count 1 -timeout 10).received -eq 1) { $_ | out-file 'C:\work\lmhosts2.txt' -append } } }
```

It works but it's not nice.  I've taken a programmer's approach but done it as a one-liner.  Is there a better way of doing it, that's more 'shell' and less 'code'?

Comment: Beware of using -like.  I would use -match '^\s*#' instead. If there is an initial space the like statement won't catch it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular example, you are filtering the contents of 1 file and outputting it to another. [Where-Object](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/msh/cmdlets/where-object.mspx) is usually a good choice for this. You can then simplify your one-liner a bit:

```
gc 'C:\work\lmhosts.txt' | 
    ?{ ($_ -like '#*') -or 
       ($(Ping-Host $_.Split(' ')[0]) -count 1 -timeout 10).received -eq 1) } > 
    'C:\work\lmhosts2.txt'
```

Some notes:

- "?" is an alias for Where-Object
- The -or operator will short circuit, that is, if the first operand results in True, the second will not bother executing.
- You can use the redirection operator ">" instead of "| Out-File".
- I replaced Substring with Split, it seemed slightly simpler, not sure if works in general with your input.

Comment: I like this approach. I would just replace the Ping-Host usage with Test-Connection -quiet if you're on PowerShell 2.0.  BTW if you want to maintain the original encoding, I would drop back to Out-File -enc ascii.

Comment: Oh yeah, same comment about the brittleness of -like versus -match as I mentioned on the question post.

Comment: Ah, yes.  That looks better than mine.  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace is your friend!  In Powershell scripts I write that aren't immediately thrown away, almost every '|' is followed by a newline + indent.

Comment: Ah, but then it wouldn't be a one-liner.  :-)

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood what kind of "style" you were hoping to improve.